# Error Message pcsf-46008

Tags: informatica

I am new in Informatica. I have trouble opening Informatica PowerCenter 9. This is the Error Message

> pcsf_46008 Cannot connect to Domain (--) to lookup for service
>   (coreservices/UserManagementService)

Kindly help me in solving this issues.

Thanks,

Robin

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your domain services are not up and running, try starting the services...  how to do it would depend upon your system, for windows it would be a service (accessible through service manager), on unix like systems, you would have a daemon that needs to be started.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Ultimate. I was working on Informatica for sometime then all of sudden, this happened.

Comment: Go check if your repository database services are up and running, if so, check if your informatica services are running ?  Windows might play the trick and the firewall can block the port... check such stuff...